# After Upgrading to PHP 7.4 No MySQL

Tags: apache2, mysql, php

I updated PHP to 7.4 and according to *phpinfo()* the mysqli running is:

```
Client API library version mysqlnd 7.4.0
```

but PHP pages do not connect. The MySQL server is running as I can access it through my desktop client but it does not run with PHP. If I run this in terminal it still shows 7.3:

```
sudo apt show php -a
Package: php
Version: 2:7.3+70+ubuntu19.10.1+deb.sury.org+6
Priority: optional
Section: php
Source: php-defaults (70+ubuntu19.10.1+deb.sury.org+6)
Maintainer: Debian PHP Maintainers <team+pkg-php@tracker.debian.org>
Installed-Size: 12.3 kB
Depends: php7.3
Download-Size: 6,088 B
APT-Sources: http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 Packages
Description: server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (default)
 PHP (recursive acronym for PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor) is a widely-used
 open source general-purpose scripting language that is especially suited
 for web development and can be embedded into HTML.
 .
 This package is a dependency package, which depends on latest stable
 PHP version (currently 7.3).
```

. . . but with the -a switch, it also shows that version 7.4 is installed and is the latest stable version!

There is only the PHP 7.4 folder so no older versions are still installed but if I run *sudo apt-get install php-mysql* it tries to install support for 7.3 but if I run *apt install php7.4-mysql* it tells me that the latest version, 7.4.1, is already installed. What's going on and why the references to 7.3?

PHP 7.3 was disabled using *sudo a2dismod php7.3* and 7.4 enabled using *sudo a2enmod php7.4* so I can't figure out what's going or where it is even getting the 7.3 information.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the PHP MySQL extension using the following command:

```
apt install php7.4-mysql
```

Comment: I've already run *apt install php7.4-mysql* and it tells me that the latest version, 7.4.1, is already installed.